# Rôle des virgules dans une phrase et sens de cette phrase

Tags: sens, ponctuation

> Si, depuis le début de la crise financière de 2007, les gouvernements européens ont choisi, les experts poursuivent leurs délibérations… avec d’autant plus de prudence qu’ils font rarement partie des premières victimes des coupes budgétaires.

J'ai lu cela [dans un article politique](https://www.monde-diplomatique.fr/2014/10/BASU/50879) et je ne peux pas comprendre le sens. Pourquoi y a-t-il tellement de virgules ici, bien que, à mon avis, ces phrases ne font pas une unité.

Comment: Il vaut toujours mieux **donner la source** quand on fait une citation, ça permet de voir si l'original a été bien reproduit pour lever toute ambiguïté. Je corrige la citation en conséquence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La proposition principale est ici "les experts poursuivent leurs délibérations", avec un complement de manière qui suit les points de suspensions (qui représentent une pause dramatique)

"Si" est ici une conjunction qui introduit une subordonnée "si les gouvernements européens ont choisi". "depuis le début de la crise financière de 2007" est un complément de temps, en incise, d'où les virgules qui le sépare du reste de la subordonnée.

- les experts poursuivent leurs délibérations

  - avec d’autant plus de prudence

    - qu’ils font rarement partie des premières victimes des coupes budgétaires
  - [même] si les gouvernements européens ont choisi

    - depuis le début de la crise financière de 2007

"Si" conjonction n'introduit pas toujours une hypothèse, mais peut avoir une série de sens plus réels, auquel cas on n'utilise pas le conditionnel dans la principale. C'est le cas notamment dans les cas où "si" introduit une relation de cause à effet (1), une concession (2) ou une opposition (3):

1. S'il n'y a plus de pain, je m'en vais en chercher
2. S'il est gros, Obélix n'en est pas moins très costaud
3. Si le Real pleure le départ de Cristiano Ronaldo, Lucas Hernandez [...] a accueilli l'information avec le sourire (tiré [d'un article sportif](http://sports.tv5monde.com/lucas-hernandez-se-rejouit-transfert-de-cristiano-ronaldo-7590901.html), registre qui aime beaucoup cette construction)

Dans les deux derniers cas, on peut remplacer "si" par "même si", ce qui est usuel hors de la langue littéraire.

C'est bien ici ce sens d'opposition qu'il faut lire dans "si" : Alors que les gouvernements ont fait leur choix, les experts tergiversent encore.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!!

Answer (score 3):

Je pense qu'il est nécessaire de mettre la phrase de l'article en entier pour mieux comprendre :

> Rigueur ou relance ? Si, depuis le début de la crise financière de
>   2007, les gouvernements européens ont choisi, les experts poursuivent
>   leurs délibérations… avec d’autant plus de prudence qu’ils font
>   rarement partie des premières victimes des coupes budgétaires.

Ce n'est pas du conditionnel car la conjugaison ne correspond pas, même si un "si" est présent.

On pourrait remplacer le "Si" par "Même si" : on exprime ici que les gouvernements européens ont bel et bien choisi (entre rigueur et relance), mais les experts continuent leurs délibération prudemment.

[Construction du conditionnel](https://bescherelle.com/la-formation-du-conditionnel)

Comment: Mais dans cette citation il n'a rien été dit que les gouvernements ont bien choisi.

Comment: J'ai édité pour clarifier : les gouvernements ont bien choisi entre la rigueur ou la relance.

Comment: Je comprends maintenant. Merci beaucoup!